# 504 Gateway Time-out on Update

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, update, error-handling, server-response-time

Joomla 3.9.19

When I attempt to upgrade from 3.9.19 to 3.9.20 I am getting the following error after about 2 - 3 minutes after clicking 'update'.

> 504 Gateway Time-out
>
> The server didn't respond in time.

This is also happening whenever I try to update the Joomla 'Installer - Install from Web' plugin.

Any idea why this would be and what I can do to resolve it? Is it an issue on my web server as opposed to Joomla itself?

Comment: Check your server logs to find what requests are timing out; likely due to max_execution_time - the reason why you're reaching that limit could be a multitude of factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar 504 timeout issue when trying to run updates with one particular web host and their solution was to add the following to the start of the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_dtimeout.c>
<Files ~ ".php">
SetEnvIf Request_URI "index.php" DynamicTimeout=600
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/administrator/index.php" DynamicTimeout=600
</Files>
</IfModule>
```