# Can't access Joomla site after failed akeeba backup

Tags: joomla-3.x, akeebabackup

Sorry if this is the wrong forum but I can't find any help elsewhere.
I tried to take a backup with akeeba but it got stuck so I closed the browser but now I can't access anything. 504 Gateway Time-out everywhere.
It's been hours. Does akeeba lock anything while doing backup? How can I regain access to site and backend?

Comment: Asking about Akeeba in the scope of a Joomla project is on-topic here.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback.

Comment: The answer at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/28306/120 might help.

Comment: Have you run out of disk space?  Sorry, it's maybe a silly question, but a the creation of a large backup file might use up disk and crash the server.